# Replacement rule does not recognize parity?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule

All of the following

```
y[12]/.y[k_]-> If[EvenQ[k],a,b]
y[12]/.y[k_]-> If[OddQ[k],a,b]
y[11]/.y[k_]-> If[EvenQ[k],a,b]
y[11]/.y[k_]-> If[OddQ[k],a,b]
y[12]/.y->(If[OddQ[#],a,b]&)
y[12]/.f_[k_]-> If[EvenQ[k],a,b]
```

etc. give output `b`. Why?

Comment: It would be good to have an example to try, but my guess is that you need `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`. Try replacing `->` with `:>`.

Comment: @MassDefect Absolutely! Thanks a lot. Could you put an answer? And I still would like to know why, if you know please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mathematica, most functions with names ending in `Q` will always evaluate immediately to `True` or `False`, contrary to e.g. [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) or [`Positive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Positive.html):

```
EvenQ@5
(* False *)

EvenQ@k
(* False *)

If[True, a, b]
(* a *)

If[k, a, b]
(* If[k, a, b] *)

Positive@-3    
(* False *)

Positive@k
(* Positive[k] *)
```

Since [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) evaluates the right side immediately (contrary to [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html), where the right side is only evaluated once the values from the match are inserted), your code essentially does the following:

```
y[12] /. y[k_] -> If[EvenQ[k],a,b]
(* --> y[12] /. y[k_] -> If[False,a,b] *)
(* --> y[12] /. y[k_] -> b *)
(* --> b *)
```

Compare this with the `RuleDelayed` case:

```
y[12] /. y[k_] :> If[EvenQ[k],a,b]
(* --> If[EvenQ[12],a,b] *)
(* --> If[True,a,b] *)
(* --> a *)
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! Could you please suggest where to read about this kind of special evaluation for functions depending on the syntactic structure of their heads? It was a complete surprise to me, and it is I believe important to know. Do you know where are such things documented?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't think that "rule" `*Q` functions is explicitly documented somewhere. For a given function, you can see the behavior in the "Details & Options" section: E.g. for `EvenQ` is says: "`EvenQ[expr]` returns `False` unless `expr` is manifestly an even integer (i.e. has head `Integer`, and is even).", while for `Positive` it says: "`Positive[x]` gives `False` if `x` is manifestly a negative numerical quantity, a complex numerical quantity, or zero. Otherwise, it remains unevaluated."  - Note how `Positive` is allowed to remain unevaluated, while `EvenQ` is not.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are you avare of any other similar "special treatment" cases?

Comment: The only other case I can think of is for functions ending in `Delayed`, such as `RuleDelayed`, `SetDelayed`,... - contrary to their counterparts, the right side is only evaluated *after* the values from the match of the left side have been inserted. (As can be seen for `RuleDelayed` vs. `Rule` in the answer above)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You can also take a look at the output of `Select[Length@# > 1 &]@ReverseSortBy[Length]@GroupBy[Last@StringSplit[#, a : (___?(Not@*LowerCaseQ) ~~ ___?LowerCaseQ) :> a] &]@Names["System`*"]` - it gives a list of all symbols grouped by their suffix - some of the groups don't have a strong connection, but most do share many properties. You can take a look at the documentation of a few entries of each group to see what patterns you can spot